# Call master Object Fields Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

I do something wrong but have no idea what. The answers I found didn't help me. I'm new with salesforce, probably don't understand an obvious thing.

I'm creating print button in Visualforce, and wanted to list all related objects - employers
[image]

So put the code:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Employment">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CI_Candidate__c.Employment__r}" var="Employment">
    <apex:column value="{!Employment.CI_PRO_Account__c}"/> <apex:column value="{!Employment.Role__c}"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!Employment.Role_in_the_Company__c}"/> 
    <apex:column value="{!Employment.CI_PRO_Start_Date__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Employment.CI_PRO_End_Date__c}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Error message:

> Error: Invalid field Employment__r for SObject CI_Candidate__c

Comment: <apex:pageBlock title="Employment">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CI_Candidate__c.Employment__r}" var="Employment">
            <apex:column value="{!Employment.CI_PRO_Account__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!Employment.Role__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!Employment.Role_in_the_Company__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!Employment.CI_PRO_Start_Date__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!Employment.CI_PRO_End_Date__c}"/>    
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

Comment: It looks like you may have the wrong name for the relationship between `CI_Candidate__c` and the Employment object. Is Candidate the master and Employment the detail?

Comment: Hi, I just want to print a candidate record with its child records - I'm trying to do Print CV button. Parent object name CI_Candidate, child object name Employment. I tried the same code wiht Activities - value="{!CI_Candidate__c.Tasks} and it worked perfectly. Don't understand why it doesn't work with the custom object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you're using the wrong relationship name to access these child records. With custom objects, the relationship name is *not* just the name of the object or the plural of the name of the object, as it is in many cases with standard objects.

To find the relationship name, navigate to the lookup field that links the child object to the parent object. You'll find the relationship name defined there.

Then, in Visualforce, you can access child records with

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CI_Candidate__c.RELATIONSHIP_NAME__r}" var="Employment">
```

substituting in your relationship name.

Comment: Error: Invalid field Employment__r for SObject CI_Candidate__c

Comment: sorry, didnt notice your comment

Comment: Great - if the question is solved please consider accepting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to show children records on the page and I see that you have used `CI_Candidate__c.Employment__r`, which is not correct. This is a very good [article](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/11/how-to-display-parent-child-and.html) where you will get to know how to show parent, child and grandchildren records on a custom VF page.

Comment: Hi, I just want to print a candidate record with its child records - I'm trying to do Print CV button. Parent object name CI_Candidate, child object name Employment. I tried the same code wiht Activities - value="{!CI_Candidate__c.Tasks} and it worked perfectly. Don't understand why it doesn't work with the custom object